# How to disable ecb and cedet when running emacs in terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, emacs, elisp

I call emacs within the terminal to do quick editing of files, and would like to bypass the long load times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you improve startup times:

- For quick editing, you can always start Emacs with "emacs -q" / "emacs -no-site-file"
- You can connect to an already running (and initialized) instance of Emacs using [emacsclient](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/emacs/Emacs-Server.html)
- You can configure any package to load only on demand or manually. But that depends on how you configured it in the first place. (Did you edit .emacs? Did a package manager install it?)

Comment: the emacs -q is really handy thanks a lot. I edited the .emacs file, do you have an example of how to configure a package to load on demand on manually?

Comment: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.cedet/4410 However, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075993/emacs-using-and-initializing-cedet implies that might not work for CEDET after all.